# xeri-api aspx vb.net how to disconnect the connected company

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, xero-api

Does anybody know how I can disconnect a company from my app.

I need to disconnect a company, in order to connect a new one.

I am using XeroCoreApi in vb.net.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by logging in to the organisation in https://go.xero.com, and using the left-hand dropdown to navigate to Settings, clicking 'Connected Apps', and clicking the 'Disconnect' button next to your app.